# Как получить только первое вхождение в xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

Как получить только первые вхождения в xpath, без дочерних?
Запрос такого вида "//div" выдаст все div из документа.

Например:

```
<body>
   <div>1</div>
   <div>
     <span>2</span>
     <div>2.1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div>3.1</div>
   </div>
   <span>
     <div>4</div>
   </span>
</body>
```

Результатом операции хотелось бы увидеть не все div, а только 4 записи:

```
1
<span>2</span>
<div>2.1</div>
<div>3.1</div>
4
```

Comment: `//div[not(ancestor:: div)]`

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо, очень похоже на правду. Единственное, как я понял, он ищет нахождение вложенного div непосредственно в родителе. А если будет что-то вроде <div><span><div>ttt</div></span></div> то такое не пройдет... Под not() можно ли указывать поиск относительно родителя?

Comment: _"//div[not(ancestor::div)]"_ - это, если не ошибаюсь, то же самое, что и  "child::div".

Comment: @ИгорьИльяшенко нет, он ищет div'ы, у которых нет родительского div'а

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант должен у вас сработать

```
(//div)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

следующий xpath

```
"child::span/div/text()|child::div/node()"
```

вернет

```
1
<span>2</span>
<div>2.1</div>
<div>3.1</div>
4
```

пример на C#

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq"

var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
var pe = xe.XPathEvaluate("child::span/div/text()|child::div/node()");
foreach (var n in pe as IEnumerable<Object>) {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вам нужно получить значения всех непустых узлов.

Попробуйте такое выражение xpath:

```
//*[text()]
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yDx2S6)